# Kotlin - get sum of all element in a List

Tags: kotlin

I have a List define as `val tripList: List<Trip>`

Here is my trip class

```
data class Trip(
       val driver: Driver,
       val passengers: Set<Passenger>,
       // the trip duration in minutes
       val duration: Int,
       // the trip distance in km
       val distance: Double,
       // the percentage of discount (in 0.0..1.0 if not null)
       val discount: Double? = null
){// the total cost of the trip
    val cost: Double
    get() = (1 - (discount ?: 0.0)) * (duration + distance)}
```

I want to calculate sum of all `trip.cost` in above `tripList` list.

Can any body suggest a way?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs? https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum.html

Comment: `val sum = list.map { it.cost }.sum()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
tripList.sumBy { it.cost }
```

Edit: then if Double use this:

```
tripList.sumByDouble { it.cost }
```

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/sum-by-double.html

Comment: That won't work because `cost` is a Double. Use `sumByDouble`.

Comment: Thank you It worked.